# HTAccess rewriterule with question mark

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a question about my rewriterule, I have a RewriteRule that has a question mark in it with a parameter, the value after the parameter will never be the same, so you will end up with different numbers after the parameter.

**My link:**

```
http://www.website.com/home.html?start=96
```

**My Rewrite rule:**

```
RewriteRule ^home\.(.*)[?]start=(.*)$ http://website.com?start=$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Expected output:**

```
http://www.website.com?start=96
```

I have searched for a awnser, but I don't really know what is happing in a awnser from someone else, so I am asking this so I might have a better look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteRule only match against the path, this does not include the query string. For any other part of the URL, you need to use RewriteCond and the corresponding variable.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)start=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^home\. http://website.com?start=%1 [L,R=permanent]
```

Note: I have respected your initial patterns